# How to draw individual mesh lines in ArrayPlot

Tags: mesh, list-manipulation

Consider the following `ArrayPlot`.

```
ArrayPlot[RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {4, 5}], Mesh -> {{1, 2}, {4}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]
```

`Mesh` option allow to control the entire horizontal and vertical meshes but i want to control the mesh for individual cells. I for example want a Mesh around cell at position {2,3} but only on its left and bottom side. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add lines in desired positions using `Epilog`:

```
SeedRandom[1]
mat = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {4, 5}];
ArrayPlot[mat, 
 Epilog -> {Thick, Red, CapForm["Butt"], Line[{{2, 3}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}}]}]
```

[image]

**Update:** A function that add lines to cells in `ArrayPlot`:

```
ClearAll[addLines]
addLines[cells : {{_, _} ..}, o : OptionsPattern[ArrayPlot]] := 
  Module[{k = Length @ #},
   ArrayPlot[#, o, 
     Epilog -> {Thick, Red, CapForm["Butt"], 
       Line[{{#[[2]] - 1, k - #[[1]] + 1}, {#[[2]] - 1, 
            k - #[[1]]}, {#[[2]], k - #[[1]]}} & /@ cells]}]] &;
```

**Example:**

```
SeedRandom[1]
mat = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {6, 15}];

addLines[{{4, 7}, {2, 5}, {5, 10}}, ColorFunction -> "Pastel", Mesh -> All][mat]
```

[image]